# SQL - How to get the most recent entry with common field?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
id  | id2  | last_attempt
1   | 100  | 201
2   | 100  | 202
3   | 101  | 203
4   | 102  | 204
5   | 100  | 205
6   | 102  | 206
7   | 101  | 207
```

I want to end up with only one instance of "id2" and it must be the one with the highest "id":

```
id  | id2  | last_attempt
5   | 100  | 205
6   | 102  | 206
7   | 101  | 207
```

So I assume that I need to group by id2 and the do some kind of subquery to only include the latest items.

Any idea how to do this quickly?

Comment: This is such a common problem, that the MySQL documentation even has a chapter on that: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` to get the latest value

```
SELECT id,id2,MAX(last_attempt) FROM table GROUP BY id2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join to achieve this:

```
select a.*
from your_table a
left join your_table b on a.id2 = b.id2
    and a.id < b.id
where b.id2 is null;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/UAQ65044)

Another approach is through aggregation:

```
select a.*
from t a join (
    select id2, max(id) id
    from t
    group by id2
) b on a.id2 = b.id2 and a.id = b.id
```

#### [Demo 2](http://rextester.com/ANMC13531)

Comment: This is a duplicate question, see suggested duplicate link. It has exactly the same answer as you provided with a lot more explanation.

Comment: @Shadow - I'll submit a duplicate vote. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, id2, max(last_attempt)
from table_name
group by id2
```

Comment: Wrong answer. . . How does this solve the problem?

Comment: HI @GurV ...why so ...as per expected result set....its working fine

Comment: can you give a fiddle link with another data that you have tried

Comment: How come people are upvoting this answer? It is utterly wrong. See this demo - http://rextester.com/WDKYK19874

Comment: This answer is against the sql standard and would only work in MySQL if its sql mode settings are appropriately configured. Note that the recent versions of MySQL would reject such query with their default settings.